# Is there any good software for application planning?

Tags: linux, programming, planning, sketch

I'd like to have some app to sketch my programs before actually making them, something like basic graphics editor but preferably with some features from more vector-ish editors like adding boxes, labels, arrows, etc.

I could use full-featured vector editor but it's pretty time-consuming.

So something like a hybrid between:

- diagram editor ([yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)),
- bitmap editor ([Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/))
- vector editor ([Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/))

Also, I'd be good if it'd run on Linux, but that's not so critical